# How to exclude already-picked names in a list while doing a sort of lottery in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of 24 people, to be selected one of them weekly. By pressing F9, a random name is chosen in one cell. Then, selected name is manually input into another cell to track. The problem is, I can't exclude already-chosen names. I have the main formula like below.

I can't do it in VBA, just with basic Excel functions. What are your suggestions?

Main function:

```
=INDEX(D3:D26;RANDBETWEEN(1;COUNTA(D3:D26)))
```

- D3:D26 --> Name List Formula: `=IF(P3=FALSE;C3;"")`

Basically if the name is picked and input to M Column, It makes the cell empty.

On another column to track picked names:

```
=COUNTIF($M$3:$M$26;$C$3:$C$26)=1
```

- M3:M26 --> Names that are already picked
- C3:C26 --> Name List 2

Main problem is I don't want to see blank cells while picking names. Just the remaining ones.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you an idea of how you could approach this using a combination `FILTER()` and `COUNTIF()`:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(A1:A6,COUNTIF(B1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),A1:A6)=0),INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(x))))
```

Comment: A little shorter FILTER criteria with less inputs: =LET(x,FILTER(A1:A6,IFNA(MATCH(A1:A6,B:B,0),0)<1),INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(x))))