# Excel - semi-random ordered list from sample names

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I have a list of employee names, and I want to extract a random pair without picking the same names too frequently. I was thinking of complex ways to add a weight metric that increases for each time a name is picked but was hoping the fine folks here might have a better suggestion of how to do this?

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76962224/12634230